# What is the collection and context used for in Backbone.Collections?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

When printing out a model in a collection I see the two list of "undefined"s, `context` and `collection`, which have the same length of my backbone collection, and I was wondering what they were used for.

```
var collection = new Backbone.Collection([{x:1},{x:2},{x:3}]);
print(collection.at(0));

{
  _callbacks: {
    all: {
      next: {
        callback: function (event, model, collection, options) {...},
        context: [undefined, undefined, undefined],
        next: {}
      },
      tail: {}
    }
  },
  _escapedAttributes: {},
  _pending: {},
  _previousAttributes: {x: 1},
  _silent: {},
  attributes: {x: 1},
  changed: {},
  cid: "c11",
  collection: [undefined, undefined, undefined]
}
```

Comment: var collection = new (Backbone.Collection.extend())([{x:1},{x:2},{x:3}]);

Answer (score 3):

`context` is the "this" value in the callback of an event (check backbone documentation for using `on` method), collection is a reference to the Backbone.Collection to which Model instance belongs to - a reference which is automatically created when you create a model by adding it's data (like in your example json representation of a model) to a collection. It allows for a hierarchical communication between collections and models and also makes it easy to listen to events on the collection having access to the model only (in an item view for example)

What makes it look strange is that it shows `context` and `collection` as array of undefined values - i don't know what version of backbone and what environment you are using but if it was correct it should show there `Backbone.Collection` instance or reference which you could further expand and inspect (assuming you were using browser JS console). I would bet that your print method might be doing something strange that turns the collection references to these arrays.

Comment: You are right... I was using the print function from `docttestjs` which prints Backbone.Collections as `undefined`... I should file a bug

Comment: go for it - and ignore the comment from Krasu up there - doesn't make sense whatever he was referring to :)